# Git checkout to branch not showing correct versions of files

Tags: git

I have a repo with 3 branches: master, Stable, and dev. I made a lot of changes on the dev branch and committed them. My colleague then checked out Stable branch over the top and created a tag.

When I switched back to the dev branch the files have reverted to an older version. When I check git log I can see all the commits I made with the correct files. There are no commits on the dev branch that suggest code has been merged back.

Is it possible to get back the files or will I have to redo the whole lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a solution here, but what I use with this kind of problems is gitk or some other git GUI.

You say you can see the commits when you do `git log`, can you see the commit-ID ? You can always use that to checkout... at least to make sure nothing is lost.

Comment: I reverted to one of the previous commits then reverted that again and it's back. Really odd.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the commit references of your lost commits with "git reflog" then you can cherry-pick them.